# Input.GetAxis Key release not working on WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am doing **camera navigation (Movement/Rotation)** on `Update` event in this way:

```
void UpdateMovement()
    {

        bool accelerate = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift);
        moveDirection   = 
            new
            Vector3(
                Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, 
            0, 
            Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed);
        //moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed);
        moveDirection   = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        if (Input.GetButton("Up"))
        {
            moveDirection.y += moveSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButton("Down"))
        {
            moveDirection.y -= moveSpeed;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
        {
            moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y + scrollSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
        {
            moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y - scrollSpeed;
        }


       moveDirection *= (accelerate ? speed : moveSpeed);
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    void UpdateRotation()
    {
        if (!Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            return;

        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed;
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeed;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -90, 90);
        rotationZ = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationZ, Vector3.forward);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
        transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, Vector3.left);
    }
```

All working fine but the problem on WebGL canvas when I rotate the camera using mouse and comes out of the bound of WebGl canvas meanwhile, I also continuously press horizontal or vertical key, then release input key doesn't work. Remember I logged the key[`Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`,`Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")`] input and found that it is not reset to zero on release.

```
 Debug.Log("Hr GetAxisRaw : " + Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
 Debug.Log("Vertical : "     + Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
```

Normally when I don't use camera rotation using mouse and during this time, when i release the horizontal/vertical key, it works fine. I was previously using `Input.GetAxis` now i am using `Input.GetAxisRaw` but the problem is same.

[image: Keyboard input settings]

Comment: I had issues with webgl and this, and found which unity claims made no sense,but I had 20 people who could repro it, that somehow webgl was spamming dns and that things like zone alarm and routers with dos prevention elements actually made it so input keys ran like sloths.. Once the game is in memory it shouldnt need to be doing any further checks but somehow it was..   GetAxis is kinda buffered, try the raw one..

Comment: If you look the code and question i have already done this. But still the same issue. I amazed that i didnt find any related issue on web. Can you share any link? Further it is not make sense that this issue is related to dns or internet

Comment: I didnt say yours was definitely like mine. Only that i had seen similar.  You have multiple getaxis still in your code, rather than repeatedly calling it, why no keep the value

Comment: Oh right, there are still some GetAxis remaining, let me changed that too. I share the findings

Comment: I have replaced GetAxis, still the same issue.

Comment: Is it only when you've moved outside the window? Have you tried restraining the mouse to the window by default

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "Have you tried restraining the mouse to the window by default "

Comment: you can set the mouse not to leave the webgl window.. it is constrained

Comment: Now i can't do this as the webpage contains different html controls as well where he interacts